# How does vue v-if handle memory?

Tags: memory-management, vue.js, vue-component, single-page-application

I am building a single page app with Vue and am worried about memory usage and am unable to find solid answers to my questions.

So my questions are:

1. When you use a v-if how does it handle memory? I know the component gets dropped from the DOM but what happens to the data of that component? Does it get removed from memory and if so where does it go? Or does it hang in memory till the v-if becomes true?
2. The data I am fetching can be quite large which is why for user experience I don't want to have to Axios the data every time a user loads a section/page - so I am trying to figure out how to manage this. Any input or advice would be welcomed :)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Vuex. Then your data will persist in memory between pages / components. But use it only for data you really need to keep. Local data, so the data function in components will be deleted with your component automatically, with garbage collector. But only when you will not use the `<keep-alive>` built-in component.

Comment: Thanks for your response and although it has given me something to think about I can't approve it as an answer as it only answers half my question and doesn't give me much on memory management. I was hoping for something more in line with local storage, caching etc. Where I can hold the data till I need it or use a caching table on my DB to get it quicker. Your answer tells me to put "the data i really need" in a store that uses memory. What if the data I really need is really large? Any help on that?